# UWP use face tracking on video playback

Tags: c#, machine-learning, uwp, windows-10

In UWP it seems very easy to use FaceTracker on video capture from say the device camera. But I need to use it on video playback. Anyone has any suggestions how it can be done or any alternative paths to achieve similar result?

I would like however to have the code running locally (on the same machine or on the local network server) as opposed to calling Web services and sending them thousands of frames non stop.

*the easiest would be to:
1. convert video playback to a capture stream
2. use tracker to detect faces and also draw rectangles
3. display result as a video

I understand step 2 is all taken care of by Microsoft. I think 3 is easy. So anyone knows how to achieve step 1?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't convert the video playback to a capture stream, but you can get the VideoFrames from the [MediaPlayer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.playback.mediaplayer) by registering a [custom video effect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects) with the MediaPlayer's AddVideoEffect method.

The custom video effect is a class which implements [IBasicVideoEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/dn764788). Its ProcessFrame method will be passed a [ProcessVideoFrameContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.effects.processvideoframecontext) object which contains a InputFrame you can pass to the [FaceTracker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.faceanalysis.facetracker) and an OutputFrame which you can modify with the rectangles from the FaceTracker.

See the [custom video effects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/custom-video-effects) documentation for a walkthrough on creating and registering an effect in your app. For example purposes, it demonstrates applying the effect to a MediaComposition clip rather than to a running MediaPlayer, but the same effect class can be used in both places.